# Как задать дефолтное значение в spread операторе

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**Sources:**

image.js

```
export const makeImage = ({...prop}) =>{
    const img = document.createElement('img')

        for(let key in prop){
        if(prop.hasOwnProperty(key)){

            img[key] = prop[key]
        }

    }


    return img
}
```

main.js

```
import { makeImage } from './url-loader'
import imgUrl from './url-loader/webpack-logo.jpg'


let  NewImg = makeImage({
        src: imgUrl,
        height: '100',
        width: '100',
        alt: 'webpack-logo',
        title: "webpack"
})
```

**Question:**

Если вдруг доведется не задавать, к примеру: `height` или `width` и т.д. 
*Как сделать их значение по умолчанию??*

Comment: А для чего (с какой целью) в данном случае используется спред-оператор?

Comment: А Вы можете показать другой вариант? Без спреда нельзя как  мне кажется(честно не знаю)

Comment: @John, конкретно в текущем виде, если ты заменишь `{...prop}` на `prop` - ничего не поменяется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как задать дефолтное значение в spread операторе

Вообще-то никак, ведь сам спред-оператор не присваивает значения, и не объявляет переменных - он только "разворачивает" структурное значение на составляющие.

А при деструктуризации, как в вопросе, `...` это уже rest-оператор, его действие противоположно spread-оператору: он "сворачивает" неуказанные свойства в новую структуру.
Таким образом, выражение вида `{ ...prop }` в аргументах, просто копирует переданный объект в новый, `prop`. И, так как код в вопросе не мутирует объект из аргументов - такое копирование лишено всякого смысла.

---

В данном конкретном случае, для задания значений свойств по-умолчанию, деструктуризация не нужна вовсе (как и <s>spread</s>rest-оператор):

```
export const makeImage = props => {
  const img = document.createElement('img'); 
  return Object.assign(img, {
    height: '100',
    width: '100', 
    // ... 
  }, props);  
};
```

Деструктуризация потребовалась бы *в теле функции*, при вложенных объектах в объекте prop(s). Но он, судя по коду в вопросе - плоский (в его свойствах только примитивы: числа и строки).

Демо:

```js
const makeImage = props => {
  const img = document.createElement('img'); 
  return Object.assign(img, {
    height: '100',
    width: '100'
  }, props);  
}; 
const test = makeImage({ height: 42 }); 
console.log('ширина (дефолтная): ' + test.width); 
console.log('высота (из аргумента): ' + test.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

похоже единственный вариант - задать их в начале функции вручную.

Также можно задать значение по-умолчанию, например

```
export const makeImage = ({height=10, ...prop}) =>{
```

однако в этом случае этого поля не будет в объекте `prop` и надо будет как-то добавлять его для прохода в цикле.

Comment: В аргумент почему-то не перетирает дефолтное значение, ключи затерялись ?

Comment: @John, как ты вызываешь?